# Basic definitions of operators involving distributions

Tags: operator-theory, distribution-theory

I am quite new to dealing with operators with entries given by distributions and I would like to ask a few basic questions regarding their definitions. For simplicity let us assume that:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} \delta(t-t_{1}) & 0 \\ 0 & \delta(t-t_{2})  \end{pmatrix}$

where $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$ are two real numbers.

1. Is $A$ considered to be a self-adjoint? or what is it?
2. Is $A$ considered to be bounded or unbounded (or maybe something else)?

Comment: The delta function is actually a member of the dual of many Hilbert spaces, such as $H^1_0(\Omega)$ which would tend to confirm your suspicion that it can be treated like any other linear operator.

Comment: @Chessnerd321 About linearity I agree that it is linear. But that still leaves the questions in the post unanswered.

Comment: Can you precisely describe the space on which $A$ is supposed to be acting, the space in which it takes its values and how the action is defined?

Comment: @P.P.Tuong Good question. The space is what is spanned by the eigenvectors resulting by solving the Schrodinger equation with $A$ taken as the Hamiltonian. The action is defined as the normal matrix multiplication.

Comment: I would certainly call that self-adjoint since it's diagonal and real-valued. But bounded... no, not globally, but for $t\not\in\{t_1,t_2\}$ it's certainly bounded (since it then vanishes).

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks a lot! Well.. it is not completely real valued as infinity is not a part of the real numbers.

Comment: @Yair comments are not meant to provide full answers. Still, since all linear operators are bounded, in fact my comment does answer half of your question, assuming $A$ is being understood in a proper complete context.

Comment: @Chessnerd321: what you say that linearity implies boundness is true only if $A$ is an operator between (finite dimensional) normed spaces.